# How to Create new Array based on part of a Class from remote resource

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I very new in php programing, and I have try to search on google and this stackoverflow for this solution but still not get it

I'm using the following code;

```
$url   = 'http://best1st.info/Moviedb/json.php?m=tt2015381&o=json';
$newdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($alsoKnownAs));

$alsoKnownAs = $data['ALSO_KNOWN_AS'];
echo "<pre>";
$newdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($alsoKnownAs));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newdata);
```

I try to manipulate Array from IMDB data, if the array output like :

```
. and so on
.
.
[TOP_250] => 52
[OSCARS] => 
[AWARDS] => 
[NOMINATIONS] => 
[VOTES] => 166,773
[LANGUAGE] => Array
    (
        [0] => English
    )

[COUNTRY] => Array
    (
        [0] => USA
        [1] => UK
    )

[STORYLINE] => On planet Earth in 1988, young Peter Quill ( ) sits in the waiting room of a hospital...
[ALSO_KNOWN_AS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Guardianes de la galaxia = Argentina
        [1] => Qalaktikanin MÃ¼hafizeÃ§ileri = Azerbaijan
        [2] => ÐŸÐ°Ð·Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÐ»Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ Ð½Ð° Ð“Ð°Ð»Ð°ÐºÑ‚Ð¸ÐºÐ°Ñ‚Ð° = Bulgaria (Bulgarian title)
        [3] => GuardiÃµes da GalÃ¡xia = Brazil
    )

[RELEASE_DATES] => Array
    (
        [0] => USA = 21 July 2014
        [1] => UK = 24 July 2014
        [2] => Canada = 29 July 2014
        [3] => Argentina = 31 July 2014
.
.
. and so on
```

How I create a New Array that just have "ALSO_KNOWN_AS" values?

Thanks you

Comment: How about $newArray = $originalArray['ALSO_KNOWN_AS'] ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. As the data you require is already saved as an array you can retrieve it with;

```
$alsoKnownAs = $newdata->ALSO_KNOWN_AS;
```

So your code would look like this;

```
$url   = 'http://best1st.info/Moviedb/json.php?m=tt2015381&o=json';
$newdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

$alsoKnownAs = $newdata->ALSO_KNOWN_AS;
```

You can then loop over the values with the following;

```
foreach($alsoKnownAs as $value) {
    echo '<pre>' . $value . '</pre><br>'; // to print each row of the data
    // $value is the value of each part of the array in turn, starting from 0
}
```

Comment: sorry i confused how to print it out, can you write it for me ?

Comment: Please check at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6c46214866a5765f19605ef153665620ce3b83d

Comment: Answer edited with changes for your new information.

Comment: sorry i very new in php, still fail for me , here is my code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43bb42e2cb6637fb21bf35ccc5ab8101d6ce93b8

Comment: That's because `file_get_contents()` has been disabled on that sandbox website (and for good reason). Try your own webspace.

Comment: sorry still get massage "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42792004e768b7c86ffcdaea1e04165ec8a6dd7e

Comment: Ah, just a few moments. Will post an updated answer.

Comment: Use `$newdata->ALSO_KNOWN_AS` rather than the array selector. See edited answer.

Comment: THanks Q Worldofjr, It WORK NOW . .  you are Awesome :)